# How to build kernel module without building whole kernel?

Tags: 16.04

I have made some changes to i2c-ocores kernel code and I would like to build i2c-ocores module without building the whole kernel again. 
could you please tell me how to do it ?

I am using the following commands to build the linux kernel:

```
#download sources in current directory
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)

#Change into the downloaded directory and run following commands in order
sudo chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
sudo chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*
sudo fakeroot debian/rules clean
sudo fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
sudo fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic skipabi=true skipmodule=true
```

Comment: how is that duplicate ? I am not following standard make commands here directly. I am using ubuntu debian/rules. My question was targeted to a command to be used within this realm of execution.

Comment: Did you bother to read the answers ? Apparently not. `make drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000.ko` in your case specify the path to the module you want to build.